# Flutter, json -> map update value is not able in for statement, bug

Tags: flutter, dart

After receiving the json object, (from REST api)

jsonDecode to create a List<Map<String,dynamic>> variable,

and inside for statement, do map['key'] = anyValue; Try it.

I think I found a flutter bug.

```
 "data": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "",
            "price": null,
            "some": [
                      {
                        "needToChange": 1 (int)
                       }
                     ],
            }
         ]

List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(res.body)['data'];
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
  data['some']['needToChange'] = someArray[i]; // new int value
  print(data['some']['needToChange']); // it is changed for now but it rolls back when scope is dead
}


print(data['some']['needToChange']) // it results 1 nothing changed
```

---

FULL CODE

```
 dynamic res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(C_URL_BASE + '/v1/post-query/abc'),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
        },
        body: body);
    
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = json.decode(res.body);
    List<dynamic> myList = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonData['data']['someA'].length; i++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < jsonData['data']['someB'].length; k++) {
        if (jsonData['data']['someA'][i]['nestedA'] ==
            jsonData['data']['someB'][k]['nestedB']) {
          var map = jsonData['data']['someB'][k];
          print(jsonData['data']['someA'][i]['id']);
          map.update('needToChange',
                  (value) => jsonData['data']['someA'][i]['id']);
          myList.add(map);
        }
      }
    }

    print("it begins " + myList.length.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
      print(myList[i]['needToChange']); //nothing changed!!
    }
```

json data

```
"someA": [
          {
            "nestedA": 2,
            "id": 5
          },
          {
            "nestedA": 1,
            "id": 2
          },
          {
            "nestedA": 2,
            "id": 4
          },
          {
            "nestedA": 1,
            "id": 3
          },
          {
            "nestedA": 1,
            "id": 1
          }
        ],
        "someB": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "needToChange": 111,
           },],]
```

I added more I am sure they are list please check it out

this is all I have

I am sure this is a Flutter bug

Comment: could you add sample snippet code so we can run test it?

Comment: are you trying to get value ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yah I need to change the int data inside nested Json Objects from server and need to get lists also. and I need to use for statement

Comment: *from server* , is it server side code or user side ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the client side (Flutter)

Comment: how do you know which item in some List you are changing? @viel

Comment: @eamirho3ein I posted full code check it out

Comment: thanks, could you also include print("jsonData = $jsonData");? @viel

Comment: @eamirho3ein you mean the real json object including fields name? It is company information, so I want to but I can't help it sorry

Comment: the data you add contains list of map but you used `jsonData['data']['someA']` which means data isn't list. @viel

Comment: @eamirho3ein jsonData['data'] is not list but jsonData['data']['someA'] is a list I am sure and someB is also a list

Comment: @viel could you say what is indie jsonData['data']['someB'][k]? could you print it?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I added summary one

Answer (score 0):

The `data` and `some` are list here. You need to provide index to access the element.  You can follow this structure.

```dart
final someArray = List.generate(10, (index) => index);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   data[i]['some'][0]['needToChange'] = someArray[i];
   print(data[i]['some'][0]['needToChange']);
}
```

Comment: Um.. I think it is bit different from points

Comment: yes changing value

Comment: updated, you were missing the index

Comment: Sorry I`m afriad not, I uploaded the full code check it out please

Comment: what do you get from `print("it begins " + myList.length.toString());`

Comment: I get "it begins 5" the length is correct but the number rolls back

Comment: Do you get all data properly here `print(jsonData['data']['someA'][i]['id']);`

Comment: Yup, my json data is all 3-4 nested, and all key value values come out very perfectly without missing one. I checked and checked very thoroughly for 24 hours. I am sure, The only problem is that the value value is changed inside the for statement, but not changed when printed outside.

Comment: `needToChange` key doesnt include on main map. Try to replace `map.update('needToChange',..` with this format `data[i]['some'][0]['needToChange'] = someArray[i];`

Comment: I already did that too my friend It didn't work so I changed it to that one. (and it prints well so inside for statement)