# Flutter, Dart, add nested map to map

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var a = {
   'field1' : 'one'
   'field2' : 'two'
}
```

and then I want to add map b.

so I tried

```
a['b'] = {
  'nestedKey':{
     'field1' : 'one'
   }
};
```

but it occurs error. how do I acheive this?

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?' of 'value'
```

---

eamirho3ein's answer is working but this is still not working
I add more   this is not working

```
                      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ScreenB(
                                    args: {
                                      'oldfield': 'old' 
                                    },
                                  )),
                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);




import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  final args;
  const ScreenB({Key? key, required this.args}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    args['newfield'] ={
      'nested':{
        'field1' : 'one'
      }
    };
    print($args);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: could you include you result and also error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `a` as `Map<String, dynamic>` like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> a = {'field1': 'one', 'field2': 'two'};
a['b'] = {
   'nestedKey': {'field1': 'one'}
};

print("result = $a"); // result = {field1: one, field2: two, b: {nestedKey: {field1: one}}}
```

when you define `a` as `var`, by default it takes `Map<String, String>` for its type and when you try to pass `b`, because b's value is an other `map` so you can't set it, `a` only accept string for its value. So you need to change `a` type to `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Hi, your answer is working but in my enviorment, it is not working. check my edited question please

Comment: Yah maybe, args: {
                                      'oldfield': 'old' 
                                    }, was wrong I guess.. then

Comment: could you add the place where you define args of ScreenB page?

Comment: Hi, do you know about this issue too?? Did you solve ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74509009/flutter-json-map-update-value-is-not-able-in-for-statement-bug?noredirect=1#comment131527084_74509009

Comment: @Julidi sorry I can't find its issue,